# Tensorflow : Invalid type error while defining a tf constant

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, tensorflow

I am reading the following (csv) file as a dataframe in my jupyter notebook:

```
name,gender,type,currency,age,id,sessions,amount,averageSessionDuration,numberOfActiveDays
"OjkTPVONFUTLyR","M","test","GBP",20,1247084,126,3759.799995016699,422.2407336248684,10
```

Below is the code that reads the file:

```
df = pd.read_csv(
      tf.gfile.Open("/data/historical.csv"),
      skipinitialspace=True)
```

I have an array of column names and I try to map the values into tensorflow constants, e.g.:

```
CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS = ["age", "id", "sessions", "amount", "averageSessionDuration", "numberOfActiveDays"]
continuous_cols = {k: tf.constant(df[k].values) for k in CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS}
```

While doing so, I get the following Error:

```
TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got 20.0
```

So, it looks like it is not able to derive the type from the value (for the age column). Is there anything else I need to do to make this work?

Tensorflow version : `1.13.0-rc1`

Pandas version : `0.24.1`

Docker image : `tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-py3-jupyter`

Answer (score 0):

I just ran you code. You have mistaken the key `amount` to `amounts` in the following line.

```
CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS = ["age", "id", "sessions", "amounts", "averageSessionDuration", "numberOfActiveDays"]
```

When this is corrected, it didn't give any error both with python-2.7 and python-3.5

My pandas version: `0.23.4` and tensorflow version: `1.10.1`

Comment: thanks for the update. I corrected it, however, I am still getting the same error. From the stacktrace, it seems it's failing to parse the `age` and not `amount`. Let me post a complete example if that helps. I have also updated the question with Tensorflow and pandas version.